# Android XML: Image views in a pop window don't fit, force the last one to scale

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-popupwindow

I have four imageviews in a pop up window. They are identical, in a relative layout, side by side(each one set to be to the right of the one next to them) . When they launch, they don't all fit so the fourth imageview automatically scales down. Is there a way to make them all scale down if they don't fit, so that they remain the same size?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question your are trying to showing the four images side by side in a pop up dialog . try giving `"weights"` to those images . 
Else you need to `adjust according to the screen size`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to switch to a Linear Layout.